# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XXXXXXXX in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, sbt-assembly

I have written the scala-spark code to build my project and IDE is IntelliJ and it was showing this error while running it on AWS EMR cluster and working fine on the local.

It was cracking at below commented line:

```
var join_sql="select ipfile.id,ipfile.col1,opfile.col2 from ipfile join opfile on ipfile.id=opfile.id"
var df1=Operation.spark.sql(join_sql)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
var df2 = df1.groupBy("col1","col2").count()
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
df2=Operation.spark.sql("select * from df2 order by count desc")
print("count : ",df2.count())
try {
  df2.foreach(t => {                                   
    impact=t.getAs[Long]("impact").toString              // Job was aborting at this particular line
    m1 = t.getAs[String]("col1")
    m2=t.getAs[String]("col2")
    print("m1" + "m2" )
  })
```

When I created the jar through sbt assembly to run it on the local mode, it was working fine but when I created the jar for yarn-client and executing that on cluster mode, it was showing this error.

Comment: can you add full code ??

Comment: Error is arising from foreach function. As it's too long unable to add the entire code here

Comment: add only code how are you creating df2 & its print schema ?

Comment: also why are you using foreach , any usecase ??

Comment: I edited it and using foreach so that we can iterate it over all the rows and after that we can extract the values of all the cols in the row

Comment: After extract values what will you do.. I m just trying to understand .. ur use case..

Comment: I need to do regex matching on the string values on col1, if that matches then need to apply some function on that

Comment: you can also do same without foreach ??

Comment: I have tried several things (like map, udf, foreachPartition etc.) ... nothing is working out